# I want to check User's Location Periodically at an interval of 20 Sec. automatically

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

Hello I am creating an Android App. in which i am including one Navigation module.
Here i want to check user's location automatically at an Interval of 20 Second, i don't want to put any button to fire this location change event. This method should run automatically like real-time Google Map navigation system. I am fetching user's location using `FusedLocationAPI` and `LocationListener`.
I have created this method.

```
    private void onLocationUpdate() {
    lr.setInterval(20000).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, lr, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

}
```

Here `lr` is an object of `LocationRequest`.
Please tell me where should i call this method.
And under `onLocationChanged(Location location)` i am adding marker at User's current location.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create a service:

```
public class LocationService extends Service
        implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {}
```

and implement the needed method. you will get:

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //do your stuff
    }
```

now is up to you to check if X times as pass and if you need to do something with location. Also don't forget to add

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.+'
```

in your graddle. And in your manifest add, of course the permission;

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and your service:

```
<service
        android:name="{package}.LocationService"
        android:exported="false" />
```